# window.location not setting to new value correctly

Tags: javascript, .net, webforms, window.location

I am currently having issues with a bit of javascript I am running on a website. I am trying to redirect to a new page however instead of setting the redirect url to the page I pass in it seems to concatenate it to the end of the existing url.

For example if I am current on `www.stackoverflow.com/questions` and want to go to `www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` the url becomes `www.stackoverflow.com/questions/www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`

When I output the variable containing the URL to console it appears correctly

```
var nextPage = window.location.hostname + data.redirectUrl + "?confirmationtype=success";
console.log(nextPage);
window.location.href = nextPage;
```

the above output would be `www.stackoverflow.com.au/questions/ask` but would redirect to `www.stackoverflow.com/questions/www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`

I have done some searching and in many cases it seems to be related to `onpost` methods on the form, but I cant see how this would be an issue on my page and I am using a polling timer method to trigger these calls so page posts should not be a factor. Also if I try `onpost="return false"` other pages that use the same layout fail to post :S

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is in your `data.redirectUrl`?

Comment: @AkashAmin the redirectUrl contains the url path (excluding the host) so in my example above it would be `/questions/ask`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Url without protocol ("http:") becomes relative Url - so when you try to set `window.location` it will not perform navigation.

Something similar to:

```
var nextPage = window.location.hostname + data.redirectUrl + "?confirmationtype=success";
console.log(nextPage);
window.location = "http://" + nextPage;
```

You can use `window.location.protocol` instead "http://", you can use `window.location` or `windows.location.href` in code above.

Note that your sample shows some strange `window.location.href(nextPage);` which is function call, but `href` is not a function.

Comment: I have fixed the typo I made with href, but I think you are onto something with the relative url, I am running from local host so my url does not contain the http:// component for its url! I will test this and see if it works :)

Comment: Success! Thank you very much, its very strange to have the behaviour of this method changes when there is no HTTP prefix, is there a reason why this happens?

Comment: @MatthewPigram url without scheme (protocol) does not define how to talk to server - so there is no way for browser to navigate to it. You can read details / find links to specification on any browser's documentation site - i.e. MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.